# How can i Lifting x86_64 assembly code to LLVM-IR?

Tags: virtual-machine, llvm, llvm-ir, deobfuscation, lifting

I'm researching of virus and I'm faced with the task of deobfuscating its virtual machine. I chose to do this through LLVM and I had a question, where can I see a simple example of lifting instructions to the LLVM-IR level? For example, where can I look at code that just translate one pop rsp instruction to LLVM-IR? Since I didn't find anything like that.

Maybe someone has articles where this is described or can someone suggest with an example?

Comment: You could check at what RetDec does (https://github.com/avast/retdec). It's a decompiler based on LLVM. It lifts assembly to LLVM-IR and then LLVM-IR to C.

Comment: Related: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30475/lifting-x86-machine-code-to-llvm-ir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of similar tools you could try:

1. [MeSema](https://github.com/lifting-bits/mcsema) relies on IDA Pro to disassemble a binary file and produce a control flow graph. Then it can convert the control flow graph into LLVM IR.
2. [llvm-mctoll](https://github.com/Microsoft/llvm-mctoll) is easy to use, but SIMD instructions such as SSE, AVX, and Neon cannot be raised.
3. [retdec](https://github.com/avast/retdec) is a retargetable machine-code decompiler
4. [reopt](https://github.com/GaloisInc/reopt) is a general purpose decompilation and recompilation tool, support x86-64 Linux programs.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm currently trying to rewrite this under Windows: 
https://github.com/aengelke/rellume

Maybe you know something like a library for translating code to LLVM-IR so that I can integrate this library into my code?